# Error in Adapter Android

Tags: android, adapter

It probably will be simple answer but please take a look at this error. I want to make adapter to return a View. I've been looking everywhere in network but still can not make it working. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
MAIN ACTIVITY shortly:

public void setAdapter()
    {
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.id.list_item, list);

    } 

AND ADAPTER:

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GifModel> {


    private ArrayList<GifModel> objects;
    private Context context;


    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<GifModel> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View v = convertView;


        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             // HERE IS A CRITICAL ERROR. IT CAN NOT INFLATE THIS LAYOUT AND DO NOT KNOW WHY
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newListItem, null);
        }


        GifModel i = objects.get(position);

        if (i != null) {


            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameOfTheItem);
            TextView ttd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateOfAdded);


            if (tt != null){
                tt.setText(i.getNameOfIteme());
            }
            if (ttd != null){
                ttd.setText(i.getAddedDate());
            }

        }

        // the view must be returned to our activity
        return v;

    }

END LIST ITEM VIEW:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:id="@+id/newListItem" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateOfAdded"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listImageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listImageView"
        android:text="HAHA" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameOfTheItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dateOfAdded"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listImageView"
        android:text="UMCUMC" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ratingView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameOfTheItem"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you need change name of `newListItem` to lowercase as `blackbelt` said

Comment: I've done it and nothing new has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not use camel cased name for layout file. The only allowed chars are `a-z,0-9,_`

Comment: My layout file is named : list_item.xml . I can not move forward if this error will not disappeared.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild then

Comment: list_item can not be resolved or is not a field. It even does not want to compile because of this error

Comment: check the import and be sure that the R class belongs to your project and not to the android.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was in this R calss =.=. The wrong import. Thank You for that

Answer (score 1):

It's also a good idea to declare and initialize your LayoutInflater in the constructor of the adapter, getView gets called at unpredictable times and declaring the object for it every time can lead to a lot of memory overhead.

I usually setup my adapters like this:

```
public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemsService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    // getId,etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

with

```
((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this other inflater instead?

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.newListItem, parent, false);
```

I had a similar problem, but this solved it.

Comment: Maybe your layoutinflater is null? Try other constructors, like
`final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);`. Also, you could try to post some log messages (or the simplest System.out.println(); To see what values are you working with.

Answer (score 0):

add interface ViewHolder inside of adapter. You can look up how to do it. 
and about your error, this should work:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.YourAdapterLayoutt, parent, false);
```